# Allow users to see, edit, delete only his topics in Forum in Joomla

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla-extensions, kunena

I'm working on Joomla 3.3, I installed Kunena forum extension , I need the following 
when creating users , I want each users to have access to only his posts, contents , and can't view other user's content

can you help me please

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible with Kunena Forum. Since forums are meant to be public you might need to install a Ticket system instead of forum.